# SQLAlchemy ResultProxy load rows on demand?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

So my question is when I access rows using a for loop, `ResultProxy` load results on demand? or it just loads all the rows into the memory at once.

```
for record in result_proxy:
    print(record)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the iter method in the [ResultProxy source code](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py#L864), you can see that it calls the [fetchone()](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#fetchone) DBAPI method. This should load a single row into memory from the cursor at a time.